# Safari detect when video is done playing

Tags: ios, video, mobile-safari

I have a website with a list of videos to be played with an IOS device. When the user clicks on a direct link to the video to watch, the video opens in the video player. When the video is done playing or the user hits the ok button, it takes the user back to the video list.

I need to be able to fire an event in js when the video is done playing. It doesn't appear that mobile safari actually refreshes the page, just re-displays it. Is there any events that I can hook into to detect the end of the video?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work out to be like this (untested):

```
video = document.getElementById('yourid');
video.addEventListener("ended", function(e) { 
  video.webkitExitFullScreen()
});
```

Comment: In this case, the urls are directly to a video file, not a embedded video object, so I can't hook into it directly like this.

Comment: The answer really is you can't do it without setting up an embedded video object. I'll accept this answer as this works well enough with a video object.